# Assigning one or more clinicians (user role_id =2) to patient in Laravel (Many to Many)

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

My app have a few misunderstanding i need help with. These are listed as follows:

1. A clinician can be assigned to one or more patient/s by the admin.
2. In a clinician backend he/she can only view profiles of the clients assigned by the admin.

IN User Model

```
public function patients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Patient')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

In Patient Model

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

In User Table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('phone')->unique();
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->integer('role_id')->default(2);
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

In Patient Table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('patients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->string('profilePic');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('dob');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('parent_name');
            $table->string('parent_number');
            $table->string('parent_email');
            $table->boolean('status')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('is_approved')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('patients', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Kindly Assist

Answer (score 0):

This is the example for a pivot table:

Rules:

- Need a migration to a third table
- The table's name need to be in singular and order by alphabetical order
- Ex.: patient_user with patient_id and user_id
- No need Model for this table

Add user as patient

```
$user = User:find(5);

$user->patients()->attach(1);
```

In your table patient_user you will have a record: user_id